# Getting proportions of two classifiers in Matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix (myData) of data such as:

```
      L   SCORE
[1,] "nL" 1                
[2,] "nL" 4                
[3,] "L"  4                
[4,] "L"  4                
[5,] "nL" 3                
[6,] "nL" 9   
...
...
```

And so on.

I would like to get a count of "L" and "nL" cases with respect to Score. The target output would be something like:

```
     SCORE LCount nLCount 
[1,]  1       0      1
[2,]  4       2      1   
[3,]  3       0      1              
[4,]  9       0      1
...
```

How can I achieve that? I tried using table(myData) but this does not produce the required results (I get a count based on Score, but no separated to "L" and "nL").
I'm feeling like I am missing something rather trivial here. 
How can I get the count with respect to "L" and "nL"?
Currently, myData is a (rather large) matrix, and due to memory issues I'd like to avoid converting it, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, answer found, and it was table() after all.
Simply use:

```
table(myData[,1], myData[,2])
```

viola.

-Ruslan

Comment: Just `table(myData)` will do in this case.

Comment: Just table returns something like: [1  3  4  9  L nL] [1  1  3  1  2  4]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `data.table` (remember a matrix is one type so your initial matrix is just full of characters):

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)

dcast(setDT(as.data.frame(m))[,.(count=.N),.(SCORE, L)], SCORE~L, value.var='count')
#  SCORE  L nL
#1     1 NA  1
#2     3 NA  1
#3     4  2  1
#4     9 NA  1
```

**Data**

```
m=structure(c("nL", "nL", "L", "L", "nL", "nL", "1", "4", "4", 
"4", "3", "9"), .Dim = c(6L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("L", 
"SCORE")))
```

Comment: (For now I prefer the solution that does not require change in data-type, since in this instance the data type is large)

Comment: Ha, I will never force someone to use my solution! Table is far more elegant there!